# How to map similar (but different) reflected tables to single model in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to create a model which should be a singular source of truth. For example:

```
class TheTruthModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "the_truth"
    
    truth_id: int
    now_date: datetime.date
    # more columns
```

Currently, SQL Server is being used to reflect an already existing table named TruthDatabase.dbo.truth_table.

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
metadata = Metadata("TruthDatabase.dbo")
truth_table = Table("truth_table", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

The columns in the truth_table are `TRUTH_ID, NOWDATE`. I would like to pass `truth_table` to `TheTruthModel` with a mapping of `truth_id = "TRUTH_ID"` and `now_date = "NOWDATE"`.

`the_actual_truth = TheTruthModel(engine?, metadata?, truth_table_with_column_mapping??)`

The caveat here is that a database migration is coming. The engine being used might end up being of the Postgres or MYSQL flavor, and there is no guarentee that the table name will be exactly the same, or the columns. There is a chance that both will need to be used at the same time for testing.

Similarly to the SQL Server mapping, a new mapping will need to be created so that the reflected table from the new database can also be applied to `TheTruthModel`.

What is the correct method here of setting myself up for success in the future and not having to modify `TheTruthModel`?

Comment: By "not having to modify [the model]" do you mean not having to modify it from its current state, or changing it so that it can be used with both backends without having to manually tweak it each time the backend changes? Also, how important is it to reflect the tables? If you use complete declarative mappings that *match* the existing tables you would probably find it easier to customize their behaviour (vs, reflecting the table and then hacking the models to make them "fit" the reflected table structures).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! By not having to modify [the model]", I mean the "base" model that will represent all database service instances of the the truth table (In SQL Server, Postgres, MYSQL, etc), which may not be exactly the same as far as table names, column names, etc. My reason for this is that all queries will be the same, so something like `.select(truth_table.c.truth_id)` might not work for all database services if the column names aren't the same".

Comment: And just to clarify, I'm not opposed to creating a new model class for all database instances, ie `class SQLServerTruthTable(Base)`, but I was really hoping I could some how just pass a simple dictionary mapping or something to 'TheTruthModel` class instance. `sql_truth_mapping = {"TRUTH_ID": truth_id}` where the key is the column in SQL Server and value is the column it maps to in `TheTruthModel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your model code set the table name and column names based on the backend you specify. A simple way to do that would be via an environment variable.

```py
from datetime import date
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

backend = os.environ.get("BACKEND")
if backend == "mssql":
    connection_url = "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199"
    table_name = "mssql_the_truth"
    table_cols = {
        "truth_id": "TRUTH_ID",
        "now_date": "NOWDATE"
    }
elif backend == "postgresql":
    connection_url = "postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test"
    table_name = "pg_the_truth"
    table_cols = {
        "truth_id": "id",
        "now_date": "created_date"
    }
else:
    raise ValueError("BACKEND envar missing or unrecognized")

engine = create_engine(connection_url)


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class TheTruthModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = table_name

    truth_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(table_cols["truth_id"], primary_key=True)
    now_date: Mapped[date] = mapped_column(table_cols["now_date"])


query = select(TheTruthModel).where(TheTruthModel.now_date < 3)
print(query.compile(engine))
```

If we run that and specify `mssql` as the backend then SQLAlchemy will construct queries using the SQL Server table/column names and syntax:

```
$ BACKEND=mssql python so77851410.py 
SELECT mssql_the_truth.[TRUTH_ID], mssql_the_truth.[NOWDATE] 
FROM mssql_the_truth 
WHERE mssql_the_truth.[NOWDATE] < ?
```

Then, if we run the same code by specifying `postgresql` as the backend we get the PostgreSQL equivalent

```
$ BACKEND=postgresql python so77851410.py 
SELECT pg_the_truth.id, pg_the_truth.created_date 
FROM pg_the_truth 
WHERE pg_the_truth.created_date < %(created_date_1)s
```